# Is it possible to use Mock/Fake framework in Unmanaged code?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, mstest

Is it possible to mock unmanaged code with Moles or Fake framework in MSTest.

I have a scenario where few projects in .cpp and developers want to write Unit test case using MS Test and mock dependency using Mole or fake framework if any.

Q 1.Is it possible to write .cpp test case using MSTest ?
Q 2.Is it possible to mock object using moles/fake in .cpp ?

Thanks in advance

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q 1.Is it possible to write .cpp test case using MSTest ?

> Yes. But note that C++ UTs using mstest were written using managed C++ wrappers. So note exactly native UTs. 
>   Now since [VS2012 It is possible to write purely native UTs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270864.aspx) or plugin a framework of your choice like googletest
>
> In user terms you need to use vstest.console.exe for execution of such tests instead of mstest.exe

Q 2.Is it possible to mock object using moles/fake in .cpp ?

> No. Moles and Fakes are built for managed code and do not work on native code. googlemock is a library available for mocking in native